# Unexplained timeouts and delays on getting the response from HttpClient SendAsync requests

Tags: c#, async-await, threadpool, dotnet-httpclient

We have a .NET 4.7.2 that is using a mixture of asynchronous and synchronous code (i understand its a no-no). We are using NancyFX on a windows service. The service gets rest calls and makes rest calls. Thread pool seems healthy (whole process only using 70 threads). For some reason, some http responses are being delayed by 10s of seconds and sometimes by 100s of seconds and leading to a task cancelation.

Here is how the code is structured

```
public async Task<Guid> SomeFunction()
{
   ...
   var response = await _httpClient.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
   ...
}
```

```
SomeFunction().Result
```

First, I thought for sure the response was being delayed on the network somewhere for some reason. But we've ruled that out multiple ways, most significantly by looking at the ETW trace through perfview and seeing the packet make it back almost instantly (using Microsoft-Windows-NDIS-PacketCapture/PacketFragment)

Secondly then, I was sure this had to do with threadpool issues caused by the .Result code on async methods. However, again, the threads on the process stay steady at 70 threads. Through perfview i can see that starvation is really not happening (using Microsoft-Windows-DotNETRuntime/ThreadPoolWorkerThreadAdjustment/Adjustment)

I've also thought maybe I'm hitting into a deadlock situation with await/async and .Result, but a deadlock would imply that the request would never complete, not that it would be delayed by 10s of seconds.

I've also double checked that we are only using one instance of httpclient and we indeed are.

What else could it be?

At this point we are removing the .Result and replacing it with proper async/await. But I have no proof that this will solve the issue since I'm not seeing any evidence of deadlocks or thread exhaustion.

Here is a perfview analysis
[image]

We're also looking at the suggestion that we are exhausting http connections in some capacity. One reason i don't think its the case is that, according to perfview, the request is being sent out and packets make it back, but the response just doesn't make it up the c# stack. However these performance counters might indicate that there is some queuing going on.

[image]

**Update**
We have increased the http connections with this and it seems to take effect.

```
<connectionManagement>
  <add address="*" maxconnection="1024"/>
</connectionManagement>
```

The queuing shown above is completely gone. However the problem of these requests not completing remains

Comment: how many instances of HttpClient you are creating? Maybe your issue is related to maximum number of connections open to API. Take a look here: https://www.aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/

Comment: Only using one instance - and not getting any socket exceptions to show that we are exhausting sockets

Comment: Could you try adding this statement at the application's start: `ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(200, 200);`, and see if it makes any difference? This is not suggested as a fix, but as a way to troubleshoot the problem.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I just tried it and that seems to maybe have reduced the problem but not eliminated it. I'll need to wait till tomorrow morning to compare apples to apples but the problem still appears. I would be surprised though if this would fix the issue because before before this change, threads according to task manager hovered at 71 (plenty of room to grow). Now threads hover at 140 which is also strange because I asked it to start at 200.

Comment: FYI the `SetMinThreads` API has not the effect of creating instantly the specified number of threads. It just ensures that all requests for background work will be satisfied instantly by creating a new thread, until this threshold is reached. After that, the `ThreadPool` switches to a conservative algorithm that waits for 500 msec for some currently running job to complete, before injecting a new thread to the pool.

Comment: Confirmed that the SetMinThreads to 200 did not improve things. We've got 100s of task cancelations.

Answer (score 2):

> What else could it be?

You've already checked my first guess, which would be thread pool starvation.

There's another possibility, depending on how the API calls are done. If there are many simultaneous requests to the same host, it is possible that the .NET networking stack may be throttling you. Non-ASP.NET apps have a default throttling of 2 simultaneous requests to the same host. In this case you have a server app but not an ASP.NET app, so you'd have that rather restrictive throttling on by default.

Recommendation: put this code in your startup:

```
ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = int.MaxValue;
```

Note that .NET Core does not throttle client HTTP requests by default, so this is just emulating the behavior which is the default on modern .NET platforms.

Comment: I'll try this. Do you know if there is a way to prove this before trying it? Any clues that this is in fact what is happening? Can i just dump out ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit and if its 2 or something then i know?

Comment: @Mark: I don't know if there's an easy way to prove it. There may be diagnostic logs somewhere, but this is old .NET Framework code so who knows.

Comment: I tried this <connectionManagement>
  <add address="*" maxconnection="1024"/>
</connectionManagement> and that seemed to reduce the queueing that i was seeing in some performance counters (see update on main question) but did not eliminate the problem. Communication is being started and the request is always being sent (the remote server receives it and responds), but the process just can't receive it properly.

Comment: Usually, a delay in processing the response is an indicator of thread pool exhaustion.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for everyone who helped. In the end, nothing was a smoking gun. I couldn't prove thread starvation or http connection starvation. We ended up cleaning up our async/await code completed to remove things like .Result and added some caching and the problem went away.

My final guess is it's some edge case blocking in .net 4.7.2 when you mix and match async/await and .Result and have lots of requests going out.